# Probability lottery question with multiple variables to account for

Tags: probability, lotteries

Consider a state lottery where you get to choose 8 numbers from 1 to 80, no repetition allowed. The Lottery Commission chooses 11 from those 80 numbers, again no repetition. You win the lottery if at least 7 of your numbers are there in the 11 chosen by the Lottery Commission. What is the probability of winning the lottery?

---

I just wanted to check if what I am thinking is correct or not.

Sample size = $80 \choose 8$

Winning Events = $11 \choose 7$ * $73\choose 1$   $~$   $\bigg($i.e.  $11\choose7$ if at least 7 number matches and $73\choose 1$ for $8^{th}$ number can be anything $\bigg)$

Therefore, the probability is given by:

$$ P = \frac{{11 \choose 7}  {73 \choose 1} }{80 \choose 8}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample size is OK but Winning Events = $${11 \choose 7} * {69\choose 1} +{11 \choose 8} * {69\choose 0} $$

Comment: I thought that way but then I thought this is more correct $\frac{{11 \choose 7}  {73 \choose 1}}{80 \choose 8}$ as $73 \choose 1$ will also include for the fact when all the 8th number also matches. As winning is when at least 7 numbers match that means 8th number can be anything- either from the 11 number chosen by lottery commision or any other number which is included in rest of 73 numbers. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Yes, but in this case you are overcounting. Say commison numbers are 1 to 11. Then as you counted, the first 7 numbers are from that 11 and 8 number could be also, say 10. But now you have also this situation if you choose first 1,2,...,6 and 10 among first 11 and then 8-th number is 7.

Comment: I hope I made clear this :)

Comment: thank you very much that is clear now.